# Swift: Dynamically created buttons not working - how to write function that only acts on elements within parent UIView

Tags: jquery, ios, swift, xcode6

I am new to writing Swift and have encountered a problem that I can imagine is quite a common scenario - I give an example scenario here but I am ideally looking for as generic a solution as possible.

**Situation**

I am dynamically creating UIViews by for looping through an array and adding them as subViews to the main view. To these UIViews I also add 'children', a button and a label in this case but it could be many things. I would like that when the button is clicked the label text should change but only for the element (UIView) the user is acting on.

**Problem**

How can I write the button function so that it only acts on the label in its shared parent UIView? I think I understand why it doesn't work - it is trying to act on something with name 'testLabel' however since there are multiple instances of 'testLabel', it doesn't know what to do.

In jquery, in this situation I would write something like

```
$('.testButton').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.testLabel').text("changed");
});
```

So although the button class is generic, when it is clicked, it looks to its own parent and finds the instance of the label. I don't know if there is a similar concept in Swift, I know there is self but that only applies to classes if I understand correctly, not just parent views.

I appreciate this is a very different language and perhaps I am thinking about this in the wrong way but it seems like something that must be needed all the time.

Below is my swift code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var testitemsArray = ["dynamic one", "dynamic two", "dynamic three"]
var testconstraintsArray: [String] = []
var testView = UIView()
var testLabel = UILabel()
var testButton = UIButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //dictinary for position constraints

    var testviewsDict = [
        "view" : view
    ]

    for (index, element) in enumerate(testitemsArray) {

        //create elements
        let testView = UIView()
        let testLabel = UILabel()
        let testButton = UIButton()

        //add elements to constraints array
        testviewsDict["testView\(index)"] = testView
        testviewsDict["testLabel"] = testLabel
        testviewsDict["testButton"] = testButton

        //add items to view with styles and constraints

        //testView
        testView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        view.addSubview(testView)

            //add horizontal constraints for testView(s)
            view.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
                "H:|-16-[testView\(index)]-16-|",
                options: nil,
                metrics: nil,
                views: testviewsDict
            )
            )

            //Vertical position constraints for testView(s)
            testconstraintsArray.append("-16-[testView\(index)(100)]")

        //testLabel
        testLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        testLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        testLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        testLabel.text = element
        testView.addSubview(testLabel)

            //add vertical constraints for testLabel
            testView.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
                "V:|-8-[testLabel(32)]",
                options: nil,
                metrics: nil,
                views: testviewsDict
            )
            )

            //add vertical constraints for testLabel
            testView.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
                "H:|-8-[testLabel]-8-|",
                options: nil,
                metrics: nil,
                views: testviewsDict
            )
            )

        //testButton
        testButton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        testButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        testButton.setTitle("Test", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        testButton.addTarget(self, action: "testButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        testView.addSubview(testButton)

            //add vertical constraints for testLabel
            testView.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
                "V:[testButton(32)]-8-|",
                options: nil,
                metrics: nil,
                views: testviewsDict
            )
            )

            //add vertical constraints for testLabel
            testView.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
                "H:|-8-[testButton]-8-|",
                options: nil,
                metrics: nil,
                views: testviewsDict
            )
            )

    }//end for loop

    //join testView horizontal constraints as string store as testConstraints
    let testConstraints = "".join(testconstraintsArray)

    println(testConstraints)

    //add testConstraints to testconstraintsArray
    view.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "V:|\(testConstraints)",
            options: nil,
            metrics: nil,
            views: testviewsDict
        )
    )

    println(testconstraintsArray)

}//end viewDidLoad

//the problem function
func testButtonPressed(sender:UIButton){
    testLabel.text = "changed"
}

}
```

I have tried putting the button function within the for loop which I'm pretty sure is bad practice and doesn't work anyway. I have also tried changing the .addTarget of the button to "testView(index)" to try and scope the action that way but this does not work.

Apologies that the code is a bit lengthy with constraints etc. that distract from the actual problem but I wanted anyone who might be willing to help to be able to drop it in and visualise it immediately.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom subclass of `UIView` that knows about the `testLabel`:

```
class TestView: UIView {
    var testLabel: UILabel!
}
```

When you create the testView using the new class, store off a reference to the testLabel:

```
//create elements
let testView = TestView()  // previously UIView()
let testLabel = UILabel()
testView.testLabel = testLabel
let testButton = UIButton()
```

Then in your `testButtonPressed` function, update the `testLabel` that is associated with the `superview`:

```
func testButtonPressed(sender:UIButton){
    if let testView = sender.superview as? TestView {
        testView.testLabel.text = "changed"
    }
}
```